# Spark: StackOverflow Error in iterative algorithm implementation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, stack-overflow

I am trying to iterative algorithm in Spark using Scala but Spark throws **StackOverflowError**.
My code is

```
object demo {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val N =             60        //args(0).toInt      // Population length
val d =              60       //args(1).toInt     //Dimensions ; Number of unknown Decision variables
var Iterations =     400       //args(2).toInt     // Maximum Number of Iteration
val nP =           3         //args(3).toInt      // number of partitions

val MinVal =       -100         //args(6).toInt    //  Lower Bound
val MaxVal =      100          //args(7).toInt    //  Upper Bound
val Fmin = 0                    // Minimum Frequency
val Fmax = 1                    // Maximum Frequency
val Bandwidth = 0.001
val InitialPulseRate = 0.1
val alpha = 0.95
val gyma = 0.95

var GlobalBest_Fitness = Double.PositiveInfinity
val batList = List.fill(N)(new obj(d, MinVal, MaxVal))

batList.map { x =>
  x.fitness =SphereFunc(x.position) // Update Fitness
}
GlobalBest_Fitness = batList.minBy(_.fitness).fitness
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(locally("local")).setAppName("spark Demo")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(batList, nP)
var partitioned = rdd
partitioned.persist()
var itrU = 0
Fun(Iterations)

@tailrec
def Fun( itr: Int): RDD[obj] = itr match {
  case 0 => partitioned// Base case for recursion
  case _ => {
    itrU = Iterations - itr + 1
    partitioned =Updater(partitioned,itrU , Bandwidth)
    Fun( itr - 1) //Recursive call
    }
   }
  }
```

short snippet of error message is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$WeakClassKey.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:2505)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:348)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1134)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.writeObject(List.scala:468)
```

How can i fix this error?
I have to run this for thousands of iterations also number of dimensions (d) and population size(N) also has much larger values. I have used **tail Recursive** function so it could run in constant space but it is not behaving so.

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflow error is related with spark default config values for spark.driver and spark.executor memory allocation and its 1gb. 
sparkConfig should be updated as below. if memory all;ocation is still not sufficient try to increment value.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(locally("local")).setAppName("spark Demo").set("spark.executor.memory", "4g").set("spark.driver.memory", "4g");
```

Comment: "spark.executor.memory"
Two time same parameter setting?

Comment: I think this error is because of  long DAG (dynamic Acyclic Graph )